# How to import environment variable in awk?

Tags: awk

I have the following code:

```
export my_var=3
cat /etc/passwd | awk {'print $1'}
```

Now I need to use my my_var in my `awk` pseudo code.
How can I apply this?

Comment: I'd love to know where people are getting the idea to put the delimiting quotes **inside** the awk (or sed or whatever) script instead of around it, e.g. writing `awk {'foo'}` instead of `awk '{foo}'`.